# Google Map v2 check whether the point contains in area

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

all.
I am trying to check the point that user taps on the google map whether in specific area, does google map api v2 have any method that i can quick to use?

Comment: How is your area defined? Is it a polygon area or just a point with a radius?

Comment: YOu should be more specific. AS @Mannaz said, the answers will be more accurated if you say how is your area, or how did you defined. Polygon, circle..the area is in the same position on the map, or is a "screen area", etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html). It has [contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#contains%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29) method which returns true when given [LatLng](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) is inside bounds. If you want to get current visible region I recommend reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14700745/759007 .

Comment: bro! that is what i want!! In Google Maps API v3, there is a method same as contains(), and this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

You should use Location APIs

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Inside em, you can use:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Hope it helps you,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

yes you can using `map.setOnMapClickListener` which will return the `latlng` and you can use this where ever you need:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // your code                    
    }    
}
```