# Select Multiple Polygons on Map in Xamarin Forms (Android and iOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a Xamarin forms application that displays a map with multiple polygons on it.

Is there a way for a user to tap and drag to create a square on the map, and that will select all the polygons in that area?

Currently I use custom renders to create the polygons using Google Maps API2 for android and MapKit for iOS

Thanks,

Comment: What data structure do you use to store Polygons?Could you please post more details about your demo,e.g. a basic demo ?

Comment: I store all the polygons in a Dictionary<string, Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Polygon> and can access and change individual polygons easy enough via click events. It's just the bulk selecting I am struggling with.

Comment: You need to judge if the Polygons is contained in square area.You can check the  following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766962/google-map-v2-check-whether-the-point-contains-in-area