# Latlng Bound returns 0.0

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to fetch the boundary co-ordinates of google map.I am using google map v2.

I have written the following code:

```
try {
            Log.e(TAG, "Before init");
            initilizeMap();
            LatLngBounds curScreen = gmap.getProjection()
                    .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            System.out.println(curScreen.toString());

            //top-left corner
            double topleftlatitude=curScreen.northeast.latitude;
            double topleftlongitude=curScreen.southwest.longitude;
            System.out.println("top left==>"+topleftlatitude+"" +topleftlongitude);


            //bottom-right corner
            double bottomrightlatitude=curScreen.southwest.latitude;
            double bottomrightlongitude=curScreen.northeast.longitude;
            System.out.println("bottom right==>"+bottomrightlatitude+"" +bottomrightlongitude);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The function to **Load the map:**

```
        private void initilizeMap() {
            System.out.println("On map init");
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.customclusteredmap);

            gmap = mapFragment.getMap();

            if (gmap != null)
            {
                gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                gmap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
                gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }

        }
```

The response I am getting is:

```
07-16 11:26:58.438: I/System.out(9983): LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (0.0,0.0), northeast=lat/lng: (0.0,0.0)}
07-16 11:26:58.438: I/System.out(9983): top left==>0.00.0
07-16 11:26:58.438: I/System.out(9983): bottom right==>0.00.0
```

My map is displaying perfectly,hence I dont think there is/are any problem in `AndroidManifest.xml`,still the permissions I have taken are:

```
android:name="com.webguru.wearehere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.webguru.wearehere.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

As you can see LatLng bound always returns 0.0.What wrong I am doing??Or what I am missing??

**SOLUTION**

The problem was, **gps of the device was turned off**.As a result the device couldn't fetch the current location and was returning 0.0.

Comment: make your calculations in a Runnable `post()`ed to to any `Handler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timing issue, as your code is getting called before the map is fully drawn.

The cleanest solution would be to use the [GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback) interface, and run your code in the `onMapLoaded()` callback.

From the documentation:

> Callback interface for when the map has finished rendering. This
>   occurs after all tiles required to render the map have been fetched,
>   and all labeling is complete.

This way you're not relying on some hard-coded timing, which could fail if the map takes longer than expected to load.

Example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, OnMapLoadedCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        googleMap = map;

        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap(){

        //set this as map loaded callback
        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        try {
            Log.e("map", "Before init");
            //initilizeMap();
            LatLngBounds curScreen = googleMap.getProjection()
                    .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            System.out.println(curScreen.toString());

            //top-left corner
            double topleftlatitude=curScreen.northeast.latitude;
            double topleftlongitude=curScreen.southwest.longitude;
            System.out.println("top left==>"+topleftlatitude+" " +topleftlongitude);


            //bottom-right corner
            double bottomrightlatitude=curScreen.southwest.latitude;
            double bottomrightlongitude=curScreen.northeast.longitude;
            System.out.println("bottom right==>"+bottomrightlatitude+" " +bottomrightlongitude);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

SupportMapFragment in layout xml:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Output on first launch:

```
 E/map﹕ Before init
 I/System.out﹕ LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (-72.76405002018156,-63.281260058283806), northeast=lat/lng: (72.76406998847307,63.28122653067112)}
 I/System.out﹕ top left==>72.76406998847307 -63.281260058283806
 I/System.out﹕ bottom right==>-72.76405002018156 63.28122653067112
```

Comment: public void onMapLoaded() is not getting called

Comment: @kgandroid Are you calling `getMapAsync()`?

Comment: @kgandroid I just updated the answer to use a SupportMapFragment, but you could use the key pieces of this solution with a regular MapFragment as in the original answer as well.  The key is to have your Activity implement the correct interfaces, the `setOnMapLoadedCallback()` call, and the `onMapLoaded()` callback.  Note that you don't have to use `getMapAsync()`, but since `getMap()` is deprecated, it's recommended.