# How to get LatLng boundries of google Maps that is visible on android screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to plot (and hence create in memory) only those objects(polylines, markers etc.) which will be visible on screen. Rather than loading whole available data. One way I am thinking to solve this is to get bound on coordinates visible on screen and then filter the data accordingly. So for that I need to find the bounding coordinates of screen. If you know of any other approach feel free to suggest that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700498/android-google-maps-get-boundary-co-ordinates